# MySQL arithmetic calculation result differs between Windows and Linux

Tags: mysql

I have run this sql in windows & Linux version of mysql, and get the different result:

```
select (((((237803.3300+1659482.4400)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)+
(0.50*`(((((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+
((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6))    
-(((((360.00*((1527268.4000-1182208.5700)-((2587.0000-((5354427.3100*0.0400*6)/12.00))
+99354.4800+10550.5600)))/((((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+
((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6))*0.5))-(0.50*((2587.0000-
((5354427.3100*0.0400*6)/12.00))+99354.4800+10550.5600)))*
(((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+
((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)))/1182208.5700))-
((((237803.3300+1659482.4400)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)))) AS YF`
```

Windows version of mysql result: `105.93639914104807268662689486`

Linux version of mysql result: `144.43789669025999363208811782`

And I've been check this expression in some of other platform like java, excel, get the approximately value about: 105.93....., so I thought about that the calculation on linux mysql is incorrect or some of mysql variable set incorrect? Can anybody tell me why?

my linux version of mysql (At cloud server):

```
mysql>SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"

+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.1.8-20.1                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                              |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                 |
| version                 | 5.5.18.1-Alibaba-rds-201406-log |
| version_comment         | Source distribution             |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                          |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Rounding errors and also writing stupid code.

Comment: If it's rounding errors, it's go too far(144.44 - 105.94 = 38.5).

Comment: It is a (ridiculously) long equation and they do build up

Comment: Try to simplify the expression step by step, then you might spot where the problem lies.

Answer (score -2):

I did not look closely, but you are not selecting `FROM` anywhere

try this:

```
select (((((237803.3300+1659482.4400)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)+(0.50*(((((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6))-(((((360.00*((1527268.4000-1182208.5700)-((2587.0000-((5354427.3100*0.0400*6)/12.00))+99354.4800+10550.5600)))/((((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6))*0.5))-(0.50*((2587.0000-((5354427.3100*0.0400*6)/12.00))+99354.4800+10550.5600)))*(((((1159248.2000+687984.6000)/2.00)/1527268.4000)*30.00*6)+((((457300.0000+1707654.0300)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)))/1182208.5700))-((((237803.3300+1659482.4400)/2.00)/1182208.5700)*30.00*6)))) AS YF
FROM DUAL
```

`Answer: 105.936399141048`

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/32503/0

Comment: You do not need a `FROM` to do a calculation. No table is required

Comment: Hmm, did not know that... You always need to Select FROM something in Oracle... I do not use MySQL often. That's why there is a DUAL table.

Comment: I believe it is true in Oracle as well that you do not need the from clause in this case

Comment: Try your fiddle without the from bit.

Comment: Mysql do not need from dual clause. In my database server, whatever use from dual or not, it produced the same result: 144.4378..., Anybody can figure out the reason, not the syntax problem or mysql vs oracle different...

Comment: What is the choice of the data representation for floating point numbers? Then those rounding errors work differenctly